# Can you check for app update within your app?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to check for an app update within your app, such that when an update is available, your app will prompt the user to download the update on startup?

Comment: Accept some answers and you're more likely to find out.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, accept some answers. You're less likely to receive answers to your questions if you don't accept answers and contribute back to the community that is spending **their free time** to **help you**.

And now because I'm in a good mood, I'll answer your question.

Nope, App Updates and update alerts are all handled by the App Store app and iTunes on the desktop.

You could query a webservice from within your app that will return what the current shipping version is (which you could update when the new update is released). But you shouldn't limit the functioning of your app when an update is available or force the user to upgrade because Apple will reject your app for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the App Store Search API to get the number of the last version of your app from the store, and then compare it with the bundle version and prompt the user to update if the store version is greater than the bundle version.

http://gamesfromwithin.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/check-for-updates-from-your-ios-app/